# What are embeddings in the context of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, embeddings

I would like to find out an intuitive explanation of what are **embeddings** in the context of machine learning and neural networks. Is that essentially the same thing as a **manifold**? I've read a bunch of abstract explanations but I would appreciate one that intuitively explains what they really are, giving examples if possible.

Comment: Some discussion in the context of NN embedding layers can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182775/what-is-an-embedding-layer-in-a-neural-network